# Substring a Number Using Math or String Conversion and .Substring()

Tags: c#, performance, numbers, substring

I'm about to go through these calculation, so i thought hey why i just don't use substring, and then again i thought if it gonna be slow...

i remember a teacher from college teaching some old delphy based graphical engine, told us to try your calculation using plus instead of multiply, as it's really slow compare to multiply implementation. so the nature of math should be fast, but using so many multiplication and division...

so i though i come here and ask you that...

Some guy use integer for datetime in his web service, and i want to part it to a model...
As i said i wanted to write .toString but then i though it may be slow, so i though i gonna search first, after seeing nothing i thought of asking you, but then i realize that i have to write it before i can ask the question...

so here's sample code:

```
StartDate = Pc.ToDateTime(
    value/10000,
    (value - (value/10000)*10000)/100,
    value - ((value/10000)*10000) - (((value - (value/10000)*10000)/100)*100),
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
);
```

verses

```
Pc.ToDateTime(
    Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().SubString(0,4)),
    Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().SubString(4,2)),
    Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().SubString(6,2)),
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
);
```

**EDIT**
Pc => private static readonly PersianCalendar Pc = new PersianCalendar();

**EDIT 2**

AS @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Said, i changed my first code to:

```
StartDate = Pc.ToDateTime(
    value/10000,
    value%10000/100,
    value%100,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
);
```

### **EDIT 3**

As you suggested i used a way to measure performance my self.
here i used stopwatch:

&Edit 4 : I added Ivan Stoev sample code:

```
    public ActionResult PerformanceMeasure()
    {
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        var first = 0L;
        var second = 0L;
        var third = 0L;
        var forth = 0L;

        var value = 13950812;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        pc.ToDateTime(
                value / 10000,
                (value - (value / 10000) * 10000) / 100,
                value - ((value / 10000) * 10000) - (((value - (value / 10000) * 10000) / 100) * 100),
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            );
        sw.Stop();
        first = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        sw.Reset();


        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        pc.ToDateTime(
                value / 10000,
                value % 10000 / 100,
                value % 100,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            );
        sw.Stop();
        second = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        sw.Reset();


        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        pc.ToDateTime(
                Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().Substring(0, 4)),
                Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().Substring(4, 2)),
                Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString().Substring(6, 2)),
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
            );
        sw.Stop();
        third = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        sw.Reset();


        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        int month, day;
        int year = Math.DivRem(Math.DivRem(value, 100, out day), 100, out month);
        pc.ToDateTime(
            year,
            month,
            day,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0);
        sw.Stop();
        forth = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        sw.Reset();

        var ms = new { First = first, Second = second, Third = third, Forth = forth };

        return Json(ms, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And Here are the Results, in multiple run

```
RUN 1:{"First":70,"Second":41,"Third":52,"Forth":42}
RUN 2:{"First":64,"Second":37,"Third":44,"Forth":37}
RUN 3:{"First":81,"Second":45,"Third":70,"Forth":47}
RUN 4:{"First":63,"Second":37,"Third":44,"Forth":38}
RUN 5:{"First":68,"Second":37,"Third":45,"Forth":37}
RUN 6:{"First":65,"Second":37,"Third":46,"Forth":38}
RUN 7:{"First":76,"Second":41,"Third":51,"Forth":41}
RUN 8:{"First":62,"Second":37,"Third":47,"Forth":37}
RUN 9:{"First":57,"Second":37,"Third":45,"Forth":37}
RUN 0:{"First":62,"Second":37,"Third":45,"Forth":38}
```

LET me add, when i run it more closely and faster, like before i start copy paste each run to here, some time Fourth was faster Second, but not all the time, It seem that once a calculation is made, that will be cached for a fraction of time. BTW still the differences wasn't that much.

Comment: ["If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster!"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because instead of asking what is faster you can check it yourself

Comment: What you've not told us is what your number represents - is it `yyyymmdd`? Is it `days since datum`? or something else.

Comment: Do you mean `DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes thats `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: Haven't you ever heard of `DateTime.Parse()`?

Comment: @BernhardHiller That's Cultural Datetime

Comment: Also, do you understand that **`value - ((value / 10000) * 10000) - (((value - (value / 10000) * 10000) / 100) * 100)`** is actually as simple as **`value % 100`?** This expression **`(value - (value/10000)*10000)/100`** can be rewritten as **`(value / 10000) % 100`** as well.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Somehow that's right, but i'm always curious, every time i meet a new code, that do the same as something i did before, or i can do it somehow else, i can't stop it, i always gonna look for it. BTW which method do you use to test the performance?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev i forgot about that, and i didn't even think of mode at that time :D, i was so concerned about prepare it to ask this quest. thank you, that gonna be lot less calculation in the cpu, and registeries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used properly, math is always better than going thru double conversion from value to string and string to other value.

Just don't duplicate the calculations. Use local variables for storing the intermediate results. Especially with such calculations that involve division and modulus.

In the concrete case, IMO the optimal solution is as follows:

```
static DateTime ToDateTime(int value)
{
    int month, day;
    int year = Math.DivRem(Math.DivRem(value, 100, out day), 100, out month);
    return Pc.ToDateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You are Correct as Well as the performance measuring says, but you are wrong in one place, but to make sure i tried yours too,.. it's sometime faster sometime slower... the experience i had were in some game engine, i had a variable field get filled on each frame, when the user had collision with that object my framerate dropped to half a second or worse, so at some point i add a multi conditional if and it went up to 400FPS, so i got that if we read value from memory it take much less time than writing it, i know that even logical stuff need to write things, but it will be more local, so

Comment: it won't be matter in local registry and cache of the CPU, I'm not sure if what i say is right, if computer really work that way, maybe that field that i field itself had connection to else were, but it was so massive differences i couldn't forgot, and i thought about it this way. the only explanation i could come up with

Comment: I guess it's a matter of JIT optimizations. Since Intel CPU division instruction returns both result and remainder, with proper optimization the 2 `DivRem` calls would be just 2 CPU instructions :)

Comment: while mine can be more, also when we don't check optimization on project setting, cause it need it for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Forget speed, neither of your ways are efficient from a understandability/maintenance point of view.

What you should do is simply this:

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Don't try to optimize your program prematurely. This is unlikely to be a bottleneck any time soon.

Comment: i do not use gregorian calendar That's why i pass them to the PersianCalendar, it seem that i miss that

Comment: @deadManN that third parameter where I have passed `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` could also be the culture info appropriate - ie `new CultureInfo(“fa-Ir”)` - you might like to see if that has the behaviour you expect (I'm afraid I dont know how persian calendar behaves differently to gregorian)

Comment: yeah, and i don't know why, but microsoft use gregorian calendar inside that culture, it's long time error, which always been there, and there are so many line of code you have to right to make that almost correct